# Integrating elements of a Lie group with respect to parameters of the corresponding Lie algebra

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, mathematics, lie-algebra, integration

I am working with an operator $\textbf{M}$ that is represented by the Lie group SO(1,3), thus it can be written as,
$$
 \textbf{M} = \exp{\textbf{L}}
$$
where,
$$
\textbf{L} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0&a&b&c\\
 a&0&d&e\\
 b&-d&0&f\\
 c&-e&-f&0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I need to integrate $\textbf{M}$ with respect to one or more of the parameters of $\textbf{L}$, for example,
$$
 \textbf{B}=\int_{0}^{T}\textbf{M}\,da
$$
is the integral of $\textbf{M}$ with respect to the differential parameter $a$. This integration can be performed component-wise as,
$$
B_{i,j}=\int_{0}^{T}M_{i,j}\,da
$$
But, the analytic form of $\textbf{M}$ is very cumbersome to work with when all the parameters of $\textbf{L}$ are non-zero. I am having a very difficult time obtaining analytic solutions for the elements of $\textbf{B}$ in terms of the elements of $\textbf{L}$. It is possible to perform the integration on the Lie algebra before the exponential map? Or are there any simplifications that arise from knowledge of the group symmetry? I searched for a long time but cannot find a way to write the integration in terms of $\textbf{L}$ directly.

Comment: Doing it component wise might simplify the integration, but I do not think there is a direct way to get the components out of the exponential map. Do the parameters are in such a way that a certain power of $L$ becomes easier? Then an expansion of the exponential might be worthwhile (it is for $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ with $\sigma_1$ for instance).

Comment: I don't understand the integral.  Are $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$ given as functions of $a$?  Are they constant w.r.t $a$?  And is AccFoTr correct in claiming that this is a one-parameter Lie group?   (In particular, is it really a homomorphism?)

Comment: On a related note, I'm just about to post a paper to the arxiv on integrating in the group $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, where one method I apply is to map it back to an integration in the algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$.  I also talk about generalizations to other groups, but I'm not sure (depending on your answers to my questions above) that it would help if you're looking for analytical results.

Comment: Echoing @Mike's above comment: If $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$ are constants independent of the integration variable $a$, then OP's integral is of the form $\int_0^T \! da \exp\left[\textbf{L}_0 + a \textbf{L}_1 \right]$, where the two $a$-independent constant matrices $\textbf{L}_0$ and $\textbf{L}_1$ do _not_ commute in general, so no simple formula should be expected in general.

Comment: @Mike I have no idea what I was thinking about! for fixed $b,c,d,e,f$, SO(1,3) is **not** a one-parameter group w.r.t. $a$. My answer was blatantly wrong! [for example, note that the generators are not even invertible, so $\phi'^{-1}(0)$ is not defined...]

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for not producing a most general answer for arbitrary Lie groups,
(which you might tease with *great effort* out of [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map) ), but only a trail-map for your particular (charmed!) problem.

I call it charmed because it should remind you of the Lorentz group, with *a,b,c* parameterizing *Kx,Ky,Kz* boosts and *d,e,f* the three ***J*** rotation angles. Decent treatments of the representations of the Lorentz group [for starters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#The_Lie_algebra) would remind you that you may take linear combinations of the *K*s and *J*s that commute with each other, and so then your exponential is really the direct product of two exponentials, $\exp({\bf \theta \cdot A}) \otimes \exp ({\bf \phi \cdot B})$ each in a 2x2 complexified rep, with ***θ*** and ***φ*** awful complex angles you are meant to map your 6 angles to. Once you have done that, though, since exponentiated Pauli matrices have a standard 
resolution [linear in Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector), your integral is tractable---and, more interestingly, expressible as the direct product of exponentials, whence, reversing your steps, as an exponential of a 4x4 matrix, if desired.

It may be a lot of work, but it is straightforward. (Try with all parameters vanishing except *a* and *f* first: you have ${\bf M}=\exp(a \sigma_1,~ if\sigma_2) $ in the two separable 2x2 blocks; you can then see the second block factors out and is unaffected by the integration, while the first one is not, and the integral of **M** is thus ${\bf B}=\int {\bf M}=\exp(\frac{T}{2} \sigma_1 +1\!\!1 \log(2 \sinh(T/2)),~ if\sigma_2) $.) There might be a slick physical, [Wigner rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation)-style argument too, but it might take as much time.